# Ruby gsub through array

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have an array

```
arr = ['10kg','5kg','7','15kg','25']
```

So I want to remove all `kg` if it exists, return string

```
"'10kg','5kg','7kg','15kg','25kg'"
```

I have tried

```
kgs = arr.split(',').gsub('kg','')+'kg'
```

but it is bad solution.

Comment: remove `kg` and still return in?...

Comment: _"remove all kg if it exists"_ – it seems like you want to _add_ `kg` if it is missing. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @Stefan i want remove if exists and add if absent :)

Comment: remove if exists and add if absent would result in `['10','5','7kg','15','25kg']`. So you should either understand what you want, or change the desired output *you have provided* if *remove if exists and add if absent* is indeed what you want.

Comment: Please, make sure you either accept an answer if any of given ones solved your problem or edit the question to make it more clear, because at the moment the expected output you've provided and your comment are contradictory.

Answer (score 6):

```
a.map { |str| "'#{str.to_i}kg'" }.join(',')
#=> "'10kg','5kg','7kg','15kg','25kg'"
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but in real life I think I'd use `"'#{str[/\d+/]}kg'"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yea, this looks more real-lifeish. Please feel free to edit the answer with this option since I am off the laptop at the moment

Comment: Best to leave as is. Readers eat up clever answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
['10kg','5kg','7','15kg','25'].map(&:to_i).map { |e| "#{e}kg" }
#⇒ [
#  [0] "10kg",
#  [1] "5kg",
#  [2] "7kg",
#  [3] "15kg",
#  [4] "25kg"
# ]

['10kg','5kg','7','15kg','25'].map(&:to_i)
                              .map { |e| "'#{e}kg'" }
                              .join(',')
#⇒ "'10kg','5kg','7kg','15kg','25kg'"
```

Comment: If you're using `.to_i` to chomp off the `kg` part, which isn't a terrible idea, why not just `"'#{e.to_i}kg'"`?

Comment: @tadman I was trying to answer both questions “I want to remove all kg if it exists” and “return string” in one :)

Comment: The original question raises more questions than it should, but I like your approach to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna to add `kg` string into all elements jo can just use this

```
arr.map{|s| s[/kg$/] ? s : s + 'kg'}.join(', ')
# => "10kg, 5kg, 7kg, 15kg, 25kg"
```

Or if you wanna to "remove if exists and add if absent".

```
arr.map{|s| s[/kg$/] ? s.gsub('kg', '') : s + 'kg'}.join(', ')
# => "10, 5, 7kg, 15, 25kg"
```